# Agile tool with SharePoint

Tags: project-management, agile, scrum

I would like to know if you are aware of SharePoint tools (I mean template, site, ...) to manage project the Agile way.

After some research, I've found one 21scrum ... Any other ideas ?

Regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Team Foundation Server (TFS). You will install Scrum project template to TFS and you will get Team Protal (for collaboration) in SharePoint services or SharePoint. Reports will be served by SQL Server Reporting Services and project management will be done either through Visual Studio or Web Client.

Sharepoint itself is more for collaborating, document management or content management. It is not project management tool but sure there can be applications / templates based on sharepoint which will do that but market in this area is very small (in most cases Scrum teams don't want tool on top of Sharepoint). You can check [this template](http://scrum.codeplex.com/).

Comment: 21Scrume (http://www.21scrum.com/) has also something dedicated to SharePoint.

Comment: Yes I didn't mention it because it was already in your question as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of SharePoint tools to manage agile projects! However, I recently started using [Microsoft Project software](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us/default.aspx) which supports Agile Project Management. It assists project managers in developing plans, assigning resources to tasks, tracking progress, managing budgets and analyzing workloads. Suggest you check it out and try the free trial version if it helps. :)

Comment: I ended up with TFS behinf the scene and SharePoint as Front-end.